# Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile ./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0-alpha-1.zip.jar

Tags: protractor, webdriver-manager

When running `webdriver-manager update`, it downloads a file with -alpha-1.zip.jar. This does not appear to be the right file format. The example below is to just download the selenium standalone jar file:

```
> ./webdriver-manager update --standalone --chrome false --gecko false

webdriver-manager: using global installed version 12.1.1
[13:34:08] I/downloader - curl -o/path/to/selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0-alpha-1.zip.jar https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/4.0/selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0-alpha-1.zip
```

This is an invalid file when trying to run `webdriver-manager start`. What's going on and how do we fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### For context, what was happening in 12.1.1?

We download the xml file from https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com. This xml file previously did not have .zip files. So webdriver-manager update would find the latest from this list. For the `3.141/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59` the xml Contents has only a jar file:

```
<Contents>
  <Key>3.141/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar</Key>
  <Generation>1542184006302312</Generation>
  <MetaGeneration>1</MetaGeneration>
  <LastModified>2018-11-14T08:26:46.300Z</LastModified>
  <ETag>"947e57925b4185ae04d03ceec175a34a"</ETag>
  <Size>10649948</Size>
</Contents>
```

When 4.0.0-alpha.1 was released the xml file has both a jar and zip extension:

```
<Contents>
  <Key>4.0/selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0-alpha-1.jar</Key>
  <Generation>1556122620115927</Generation>
  <MetaGeneration>1</MetaGeneration>
  <LastModified>2019-04-24T16:17:00.115Z</LastModified>
  <ETag>"ac553ec987d16d2af8c8e3ef9061772c"</ETag>
  <Size>12564804</Size>
</Contents>
<Contents>
  <Key>4.0/selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0-alpha-1.zip</Key>
  <Generation>1556122620996687</Generation>
  <MetaGeneration>1</MetaGeneration>
  <LastModified>2019-04-24T16:17:00.996Z</LastModified>
  <ETag>"1974b11f970bad6e15c84e3840ec3897"</ETag>
  <Size>12342093</Size>
</Contents>
```

During the download, it was taking the first Contents Key that matched the latest version. So the assumption was that it would be a jar file and did not check the file extension. As part of the rename process, it would generate the file name. This was a pattern used for chromedriver where we would tack on the version to the binary. So chromedriver binary would be renamed to chromedriver_2.44. This is why we have a `.zip.jar` file.

In addition, we were not downloading beta versions of jar files. Another issue is that it is downloading an alpha version.

### How to update your webdriver-manager to 12.1.4?

Huzzah! This is an issue that is now resolved with webdriver-manager@12.1.2 released yesterday morning. But 12.1.4 has all the other fixes (More info here: [When using Protractor 5.4.2, webdriver-manager downloads 2.46 which is not compatible with Chrome 74](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55910242/when-using-protractor-5-4-2-webdriver-manager-downloads-2-46-which-is-not-compa/55911176#55911176))

It fixes downloading the `.zip` file and renaming it to a `.zip.jar`. It will only download jar files. Also we are not downloading alpha and beta versions of the jar. We should use stable versions of selenium standalone server.

#### To update to 12.1.4 if you are using Protractor:

- It should get the latest version of webdriver-manager based on ["webdriver-manager": "^12.0.6"](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/5.4.2/package.json#L29). So to get this, you'll need to force install your node modules (`npm install -f`) or clean your workspace (removing your node modules and doing a fresh install).

#### If you are using webdriver-manager installed globally:

- `npm install -g webdriver-manager@12.1.4`

### Links

The issues that have tracked this in Protractor and webdriver manager are: 
- [angular/protractor#5224](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5224)
- [angular/webdriver-manager#370](https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/370)

The fix to this was in pull request: [angular/webdriver-manager#371](https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/pull/371).

Other post for StackOverflow for the other fixes: [When using Protractor 5.4.2, webdriver-manager downloads 2.46 which is not compatible with Chrome 74](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55910242/when-using-protractor-5-4-2-webdriver-manager-downloads-2-46-which-is-not-compa/55911176#55911176)